# Ffmpeg multitrack live streaming is breaking when source becomes a bit unstable

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming

I am struggling with Ffmpeg live streaming where my input is from many live RTMP streams and my output is multitrack live mpegts stream, the idea is that I am getting input from multiple live RTMP streams and outputting it to a single multitrack mpegts stream which then I play in browser using HLS.js, for pulling and pushing I am using Flussonic media server.

Now the problem is that a little interruption in the input stream is breaking the Ffmpeg process and sometimes it will remove a track from the output!
The interruption in some of the inputs is sometimes expected because it's coming from different services.

So my questions are:

1. Is Ffmpeg the right tool for doing this kind of tasks? If not what else I should try?
2. Can we set timeout in Ffmpeg so that it add blank frames/fallback until the source is stable again?
3. There is also possibility of change in the input audio codec while streaming but if we are transcoding the output so it should not be an issue right?

Here is my Ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://myDomain.com:1935/app/stream1/key -i rtmp://myDomain.com:1935/app/stream2/key -preset ultrafast -bufsize 1000k -map 0:a -metadata:s:a:0 title=en-US -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -map 1:a -metadata:s:a:1 title=es-ES -metadata:s:a:1 language=spa -map 0:v -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -g 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts https://myDomain:443/multitrack/streamName/mpegts
```

Thanks